# MUI Modal container prop not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to show Modal only over some elelement, so I use `container` prop from `Modal` component, but this does nothing:

```
import { Modal, Box } from "@mui/material"
import { useRef, useState } from 'react'

export function MyComponent() {
    const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(true)
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
    return (
        <>
            <div ref={ref} style={{ width: '50px', height: '50px' }}>
                <button onClick={() => setModalOpen(true)}>
                    SHOW MODAL
                </button>
            </div>
            <Modal open={modalOpen} container={ref.current} onClose={() => setModalOpen(false)}>
                <Box sx={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>POPUP</Box>
            </Modal>
        </>
    )
}
```

I tried setting `sx={{position: 'inherit'}}` on the `Modal`, then it showed the modal at the bottom of the container, but still, whole page got the "shadow" overlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

it required setting `sx={{position: 'absolute'}} slotProps={{backdrop: { style:{position: 'inherit'}}}}` on the `Modal`:

```
<Modal 
    open={modalOpen} 
    container={ref.current} 
    onClose={() => setModalOpen(false)}
    sx={{position: 'absolute'}} 
    slotProps={{backdrop: { style:{position: 'inherit'}}}}>
    <Box sx={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>POPUP</Box>
</Modal>
```

and `position: 'relative'` on the parent:

```
<div ref={ref} style={{ width: '50px', height: '50px', position: 'relative' }}>
```